# Ubuntu server system files on SSD and Squid cache on HDD

Tags: 14.10, squid

I have one SSD with 256 GB and a HDD with 2 TB.

How do I install the OS system files on the SSD and the Squid cache on the HDD with Ubuntu server 14.10?

Comment: Your question is very unclear.  What do you mean by "the Cache"?

Comment: I want to do I install squid proxy but I want all the cache files to be stored on a hard Terra
Is the benefit of this and is it good or is it better to be on the Hard One

Comment: I'm still unsure what your question is asking.  You want to install Squid proxy... okay, got that.  That doesn't actually answer the question of "What exactly are you asking"

Comment: I understand what he wants... Edited question.

Comment: @Fabby reopened.

Answer (score 1):

When installing Ubuntu, follow the [standard installation instructions](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop) and once you come to item 4, take "something else".

Then allocate a partition with a size equal to double your RAM to "swap" and allocate the rest of your SSD to "/" and allocate your entire HDD to "/home".

When [configuring squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/Versions/v3/3.HEAD/cfgman/), uncomment the disk cache directory `#cache_dir ufs /usr/local/squid/var/cache/squid` and set it to `cache_dir ufs /home/squid/cache`

Set all the other options as per the Configuration manual for your version.